# Kivy and collide_widget not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, collision-detection, kivy, kivy-language

I'm creating a Breakout game using Python and Kivy (also with "help" from The Python Book).

The flow is: The game is constructed (the widgets are created and put in place), the clock starts and updates are ran periodically to update the position of the player and the ball.

When the ball collides with the paddle, it works! It bounces off and changes velocity as expected. However, when the ball approaches the blocks, it sails straight through them, not recognising there are even widgets there! Can anyone see something obvious I've missed?

I've attached some code:

```
class Ball(Widget):
    def update(self,dt):
        #code not included which updates velocity ( works )
        self.bounce_from_player(self.parent.player) #this works

    def bounce_from_player( self,player ):
        if self.collide_widget(player):
        #code not included which update velocity ( works )
            self.parent.destroy_blocks(self) #this doesn't work (below)


class Game(FloatLayout):
    blocks=ListProperty([])
    player=ObjectProperty([])
    ball=ObjectProperty([])

    def setup_blocks( self ):
        self.blocks=[]
        for y_jump in range(5):
            for x_jump in range(10):
                block=Block(pos_hint={'x':0.05+0.09*x_jump,'y':0.55+0.09*y_jump})
                block.colour=random.choice([(0.78,0.28,0),(0.28,0.63,0.28),(0.25,0.28,0.78)])
                self.add_widget(block)
                self.blocks.append(block)

    def update( self,d t):
        self.ball.update(dt) 
        self.player.update(dt) #code not included - this works

    def start( self,*args ):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update,1./60.)

    def destroy_blocks( self,ball ): #doesn't work
        for block in enumerate(self.blocks):
            if ball.collide_widget(block):
                y_overlap=(ball.top - block.y if ball.velocity[1]>0 else block.top - ball.y)/block.size_hint_y
                x_overlap=(ball.right - block.x if ball.velocity[0]>0 else block.right - ball.x)/block.size_hint_x
                if x_overlap<y_overlap:
                    ball.velocity[0]*=-1
                else:
                    ball.velocity[1]*=-1
                    self.remove_widget(block)
                if len(self.blocks)==0:
                    self.win()
                return #remove 1 block per frame
```

Comment: perhaps you shoul try inserting `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` and stepping through the code using the debugger.

Comment: (note that in Python3 you can simply write `1/60` instead of `1./60.`)